# Check user input against time every minute

Tags: java, swing, time

I'm building an alarm clock and I cannot set my alarm so that it can be set ahead of time the function only works if I set the alarm for the current time.I have tried using Thread.sleep and had the same outcome so any help would be appreciated, also my understanding is mainly basic so I apologize if i'm missing something simple.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

import net.aksingh.owmjapis.core.OWM;
import net.aksingh.owmjapis.api.APIException;
import net.aksingh.owmjapis.model.CurrentWeather;
import org.jfugue.player.Player;


public class Main {


private static int hour;
private static int minute;
private static int minutetext;
private static int hourtext;



public static void main(String[] args) throws APIException {


    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(320,480);
    OWM owm = new OWM("");
    CurrentWeather cwd = owm.currentWeatherByCityName("");
    int tempcorrect = 273;
    Double temp =cwd.getMainData().getTemp();
    double tempreal = (int) (temp-tempcorrect);



    JPanel mp = new JPanel();
    JPanel tp = new JPanel();
    JPanel bp = new JPanel();


    JButton b1 = new JButton("Set Alarm");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Stop");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Temperature in " + cwd.getCityName() + " is " + tempreal + " C" );
    JLabel rl = new JLabel("There is a " + cwd.getMainData().getHumidity() + "% chance of rain" );

    bp.add(b1);
    bp.add(b2);
    mp.add(l1);
    mp.add(rl);

    bp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    mp.add(tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mp.add(bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    DigitalClock myClock = new DigitalClock();
    tp.add(myClock);

    f.add(mp);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    b1.addActionListener(e -> {
        JDialog jd = new JDialog();
        JPanel j1 = new JPanel();
        jd.setSize(320,240);
        j1.setSize(180,200);
        j1.setAlignmentY(100);
        FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout();
        jd.setLayout(f1);
        jd.add(j1);

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Alarm Time (24hrs)");
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setToolTipText("Hour");
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
        t2.setToolTipText("Minutes");


        t1.setColumns(2);
        t2.setColumns(2);

        JButton b21 = new JButton("Set Alarm");
        t1.setLocation(80,300);


        j1.add(l2);


        j1.add(t1);
        j1.add(t2);

        j1.add(b21);

        b21.addActionListener(e1 -> {
            Player player = new Player();
            hourtext= Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            minutetext=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());


            //int v =1;
                if ((hourtext == hour) && (minutetext == minute)) {
                    System.out.println(hour + " : " + minute);
                    player.play("A A A A A A ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("alarm not active");

                }
        });


        jd.setVisible(true);

    });

}


public static class DigitalClock extends JPanel {

    public static String stringTime;




    public void setStringTime(String xyz) {
        this.stringTime = xyz;
    }

    public int findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return (a <= b) ? a : b;
    }

    DigitalClock() {

        Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, e -> repaint());
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        String correctionHour = (hour < 10) ? "0" : "";
        String correctionMinute = (minute < 10) ? "0" : "";
        String correctionSecond = (second < 10) ? "0" : "";
        setStringTime(correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int length = findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        Font myFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, length / 5);
        g.setFont(myFont);
        g.drawString(stringTime, length /6, length/2);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: I'd consider using `java.time` API over `Calendar`

Comment: `findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers` ... `Math.min`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Remove all the 3rd party code & trim out everything else that is not relevant to the immediate problem (setting fonts etc.). Also, remove every mention of `static`. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are really supposed to do.

Do you want to change the current time on the fly setting hour and minute value in your program?

If so,

Here is my way of DigitalClock class.

```
static class DigitalClock extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static String stringTime;

    private static String correctionHour, correctionMinute, correctionSecond;
    private static int second;
    private static Calendar now;

    DigitalClock()
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, e -> repaint());

        t1.start();

        now = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    public static void setStringTime() {
        //stringTime = xyz;
        now = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(hour != 0)
            now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        if(minute != 0)
            now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        correctionHour = (hour < 10) ? "0" : "";
        correctionMinute = (minute < 10) ? "0" : "";
        correctionSecond = (second < 10) ? "0" : "";

        stringTime = correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second;
    }

    public static void setStringTime(int _hour, int _minute) {
        hour = _hour;
        minute = _minute;
    }

    public int findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return (a <= b) ? a : b;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setStringTime();
        //setStringTime(correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int length = findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        Font myFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, length / 5);
        g.setFont(myFont);
        g.drawString(stringTime, length /6, length/2);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

I have two methods with different argument, setStringTime by method overloading.

I assume that there is no user action occurred while the value of hour and minute equals zero.

```
if(hour != 0)
    now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
if(minute != 0)
    now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

You just set the hour and minute in the ActionListener of the b21 button as follows,

```
b21.addActionListener(e1 -> {
    DigitalClock.setStringTime(hourtext, minutetext);
});
```

[image]

The entire code:

```
package justtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import org.json.JSONException;

import net.aksingh.owmjapis.CurrentWeather;
import net.aksingh.owmjapis.OpenWeatherMap;

public class WeatherView {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setSize(320, 480);
                try {
                    new Main(f, "Korea");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});

    }

}

class Main {

    private static int hour;
    private static int minute;
    private static int minutetext;
    private static int hourtext;

    //OWM owm = new OWM("");
    private OpenWeatherMap owm = new OpenWeatherMap("your registration code here!!");
    private CurrentWeather cwd;

    public double getMaxTemperatureInCelsius()
    {

        double farenheitTemperature = cwd.getMainInstance().getMaxTemperature();//Farenheit
        return (farenheitTemperature  -  32.0) *5.0/9.0;
    }

    private void setCurrentWeather(String cityName) {
        try {
            cwd = owm.currentWeatherByCityName(cityName);
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Main(final JFrame f, final String cityName) throws Exception{
        setCurrentWeather(cityName);

        int tempcorrect = 273;
        double temp = getMaxTemperatureInCelsius();
        double tempreal = (int) (temp - tempcorrect);

        JPanel mp = new JPanel();
        JPanel tp = new JPanel();
        JPanel bp = new JPanel();

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Set Alarm");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Stop");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Temperature in " + cwd.getCityName() + " is " + tempreal + " C");
        JLabel rl = new JLabel("There is a " + cwd.getMainInstance().getHumidity() + "% chance of rain");

        bp.add(b1);
        bp.add(b2);
        mp.add(l1);
        mp.add(rl);

        bp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        mp.add(tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mp.add(bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        DigitalClock myClock = new DigitalClock();
        tp.add(myClock);

        f.add(mp);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1.addActionListener(e -> {
            JDialog jd = new JDialog();
            JPanel j1 = new JPanel();
            jd.setSize(320, 240);
            j1.setSize(180, 200);
            j1.setAlignmentY(100);
            FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout();
            jd.setLayout(f1);
            jd.add(j1);

            JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Alarm Time (24hrs)");
            JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
            t1.setToolTipText("Hour");
            JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
            t2.setToolTipText("Minutes");

            t1.setColumns(2);
            t2.setColumns(2);

            JButton b21 = new JButton("Set Alarm");
            t1.setLocation(80, 300);

            j1.add(l2);

            j1.add(t1);
            j1.add(t2);

            j1.add(b21);

            b21.addActionListener(e1 -> {
                //Player player = new Player();
                hourtext = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                minutetext = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());

                // int v =1;
                if ((hourtext == hour) && (minutetext == minute)) {
                    System.out.println(hour + " : " + minute);
                    //player.play("A A A A A A ");
                    DigitalClock.setStringTime(hourtext, minutetext);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("alarm not active");

                }

                DigitalClock.setStringTime(hourtext, minutetext);
            });

            jd.setVisible(true);

        });

    }


    static class DigitalClock extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static String stringTime;

        private static String correctionHour, correctionMinute, correctionSecond;
        private static int second;
        private static Calendar now;

        DigitalClock()
        {
            Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, e -> repaint());

            t1.start();

            now = Calendar.getInstance();
        }

        public static void setStringTime() {
            //stringTime = xyz;
            now = Calendar.getInstance();

            if(hour != 0)
                now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            if(minute != 0)
                now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            correctionHour = (hour < 10) ? "0" : "";
            correctionMinute = (minute < 10) ? "0" : "";
            correctionSecond = (second < 10) ? "0" : "";

            stringTime = correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second;
        }

        public static void setStringTime(int _hour, int _minute) {
            hour = _hour;
            minute = _minute;
        }

        public int findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
            return (a <= b) ? a : b;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            setStringTime();
            //setStringTime(correctionHour + hour + ":" + correctionMinute+ minute + ":" + correctionSecond + second);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            int length = findMinimumBetweenTwoNumbers(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
            Font myFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, length / 5);
            g.setFont(myFont);
            g.drawString(stringTime, length /6, length/2);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this can help.